# Custom brushes not saved

Tags: sculpting

I spent a lot of time making custom sculpting brushes that use textures with different settings.  I assigned all of the textures a fake user.  When I saved my file and reopened it all of the textures I loaded for my brushes where unloaded.  How do I make reusable brushes in blender?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you packed them to the blend file? File > External Data > Pack all ...

Comment: Images have to be packed to be kept in file, unless you are saving them in the same location and using relative location. Packing is best.

Comment: Save data block even if it has no users. press the F for every brush then save.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out why the icon paths are being lost, follow all the steps you're doing so far and then;

1. Save the blend file to where your custom brush Icons folder is (in my case I am modifying my startup file so I've put my custom brush Icons folder into `%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\config`)
2. Then do *File > External Data > Make All Paths Absolute*.